# Best way to do a scroll pagination - react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My app has to get a list of teachers from the database and show it to the user. But, since there may be hundreds of teachers, I wanted to show them in groups of 20 that would update while the user is scrolling.
What it's the best way of doing that?
Should I get all teachers at once from the database or send a request with pagination each time?

I would appreciate any help. :)

Answer (score 1):

`React Native` supports this natively.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onendreached

```
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

const onLoadMore = () => {
  setPage(page => page + 1);
  
  // your fetch goes here...
};

<FlatList
  data={data}
  onEndReached={onLoadMore}
/>
```

Above example is a simplest version,
and there are several thing you have to consider.
(initial data fetching, loading, etc...)

Find more examples about `FlatList`, that would be helpful.